# This is a css question about the ratio of img inside the div

Tags: html, css

[image: ok]
↑ this is OK
[image: ok]
↑ this is OK
[image: not ok it's too bad]
↑ this is not ok it's too bad ,The reason why I asked

[image: html structure]

```css
.gridContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 29.5%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    padding: 10px;
}

.gridItem {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.item1 {
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
    display: flex;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    min-height: 130px;

}

.selectModeContainer {
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1px;
}

.boxesContainer {
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.gageContainer {
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;
}

.statusbox {
    color: #fffdfd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 101, 252);
    background-color: #0186f3c5;
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 12em;
    height: 10rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 1px;
}



.item2 {
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
    min-width: 378px;
}

.item2 .item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid rgba(5, 53, 245, 0.349);
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-width: 107px;
}

.item3 {
    grid-row: 2 / span 5;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    display: grid;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);

}

.gridImage {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.test {
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.responsiveImage {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.test::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 1px, transparent 1px),
        linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
}



.item4 {
    grid-row: 2 / span 3;
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 10%;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    gap: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
    /* min-height: 368px; */
}

.item>div {
    flex: 1;
}

.item10 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 5 / span 2;
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
}


.pump {
    display: flex;
}

.item5,
.item6,
.item7,
.item8,
.item9,
.item11,
.item12 {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-collapse.collapse.show {
    max-height: fit-content;
}

.accordion-body {
    max-height: fit-content;
    padding: var(--bs-accordion-body-padding-y) var(--bs-accordion-body-padding-x);
}

.button {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #ffeeca;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.blink {
    animation: blinker 3s linear infinite;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.blinkblue {
    animation: blinkerblue 3s linear infinite;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.button[disabled] {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #999;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}


@keyframes blinker {
    50% {
        opacity: 10;
        background-color: #e91e63;
    }
}

@keyframes blinkerblue {
    50% {
        opacity: 10;
        background-color: #0186f3c5;
    }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="gridContainer">
      <div class="gridItem item1">
        <div class="selectModeContainer">
          <!-- Content for selectModeContainer -->
        </div>
        <div class="boxesContainer">
          <!-- Content for boxesContainer -->
        </div>
        <div class="gageContainer">
          <!-- Content for gageContainer -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item2">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item3">
        <!-- Content for item3 -->
        <div class="gridImage">
          <div class="test">
            <img
              src="https://picsum.photos/1600/900"
              alt="Responsive Image"
              class="responsiveImage"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item4">
        <div class="pump">
          <!-- Content for pump -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="gridItem item5">
        <!-- Content for item5 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item6">
        <!-- Content for item6 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item7">
        <!-- Content for item7 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item8">
        <!-- Content for item8 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item9">
        <!-- Content for item9 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item10">
        <!-- Content for item10 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item11">
        <!-- Content for item11 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item12">
        <!-- Content for item12 -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Even if it shrinks horizontally or vertically, I hope there is an image in GridImage.
It's a coordinate calculation
The test must be the same size as the response image.
I don't know what to do because it's a condition where you can never cut an image with overFlow or make a scroll..

I tried to limit the width and height to fit-content, etc.

I adjusted the ratio of max-width, max-height, etc. top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate (-50%, -50%); I've also tried it

This shows the image too small.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `max-height` and `max-width` of the `gridImage`?

Comment: @Geshode yeah, not work

Comment: Have your tried `object-fit: cover`?

Comment: @ralph.m I must maintain the ratio, so I shouldn't use cover.
 And now it's not working.

Comment: You're already using `object-fit: contain`, I'm surprised it's not doing what you want it to do. We'll need you to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to help you further.

Comment: @BrettDonald  I modified it., I entered all the html and css currently being tested. I think you can put any image and test it.

Comment: Cover does maintain the aspect ratio, but just hides some of the image. Anyhow, your demo code is a bit too complicated, making this tricky to sort out. What's the purpose of the test div around the image?

Comment: @ralph.m 
It was originally used for react.
I have to calculate the coordinates, but I can't put the components in the img tag
Created div tag with same size as img. The div tag is test. Img and coordinate calculation components are placed inside the test.
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ
There's a test in the gridImage and an img in the test.

The usual size of the test is the same as img, and the maximum size is not out of gridImage.

However, img deviates from the test.

Comment: I have edited your question to put your code into a runnable snippet, so we can all see exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is better. I removed `display: grid` from `.item3` as well as some superfluous wrapper `div`s around the image.

```css
.gridContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 29.5%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 90vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    padding: 10px;
}

.gridItem {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.item1 {
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
    display: flex;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    min-height: 130px;

}

.selectModeContainer {
    width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 1px;
}

.boxesContainer {
    width: 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.gageContainer {
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;
}

.statusbox {
    color: #fffdfd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 101, 252);
    background-color: #0186f3c5;
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 12em;
    height: 10rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 1px;
}



.item2 {
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
    min-width: 378px;
}

.item2 .item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px solid rgba(5, 53, 245, 0.349);
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-width: 107px;
}

.item3 {
    grid-row: 2 / span 5;
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
}

.responsiveImage {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.item4 {
    grid-row: 2 / span 3;
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 10%;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    gap: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
    /* min-height: 368px; */
}

.item>div {
    flex: 1;
}

.item10 {
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 5 / span 2;
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    background-color: #ffffffc5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(5, 53, 245);
}


.pump {
    display: flex;
}

.item5,
.item6,
.item7,
.item8,
.item9,
.item11,
.item12 {
    display: none;
}

.accordion-collapse.collapse.show {
    max-height: fit-content;
}

.accordion-body {
    max-height: fit-content;
    padding: var(--bs-accordion-body-padding-y) var(--bs-accordion-body-padding-x);
}

.button {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #ffeeca;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.blink {
    animation: blinker 3s linear infinite;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.blinkblue {
    animation: blinkerblue 3s linear infinite;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}

.button[disabled] {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #999;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}


@keyframes blinker {
    50% {
        opacity: 10;
        background-color: #e91e63;
    }
}

@keyframes blinkerblue {
    50% {
        opacity: 10;
        background-color: #0186f3c5;
    }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(100%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="gridContainer">
      <div class="gridItem item1">
        <div class="selectModeContainer">
          <!-- Content for selectModeContainer -->
        </div>
        <div class="boxesContainer">
          <!-- Content for boxesContainer -->
        </div>
        <div class="gageContainer">
          <!-- Content for gageContainer -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item2">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item3">
        <!-- Content for item3 -->
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1600/900" class="responsiveImage">
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item4">
        <div class="pump">
          <!-- Content for pump -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="gridItem item5">
        <!-- Content for item5 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item6">
        <!-- Content for item6 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item7">
        <!-- Content for item7 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item8">
        <!-- Content for item8 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item9">
        <!-- Content for item9 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item10">
        <!-- Content for item10 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item11">
        <!-- Content for item11 -->
      </div>
      <div class="gridItem item12">
        <!-- Content for item12 -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm not good at explaining.
It was originally used for react.js
I have to calculate the coordinates, but I can't put the component in the img tag.
so Created div tag with same size as img. The div tag name is test. Img and coordinate calculation component are placed inside the test. 
ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ 

There's a test in the gridImage and an img in the test. The usual size of the test is the same as img, and the maximum size is not out of gridImage. However, img deviates from the test.

Comment: my explanation is weird, but...in the end

Div of the same size as the image is required.
To put the components in

Comment: Perhaps the problem was simply `display: grid`, so just try removing that while leaving your wrappers in place.

Comment: <div class="gridItem item3">
        <!-- Content for item3 -->

        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1600/900" class="responsiveImage">

      </div>

I just want to add a div of the same size as the image, but if I add it, the image is off the screen...

Disabling display:grid did not work well...

Comment: When you run the snippet in this answer, does it look the way you want it to look?

Comment: The move I want is right.

But I need more div with the same size as that image.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If it doesn't work automatically...I made a temporary prescription by designating each and every one.
I wish it was automatic...

Comment: Answers containing code should not be screenshots, but codeblocks